# Swing, mouseClicked and Z-Order

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame with null layout and two one character JLabels on the same position.

When I add a MouseListener the MouseClicked event always goes to the first JLabel even if it has a transparent pixel there. Is there a solution for this?

(eg: I display "a" and "á" and I need to know if the user clicked on the character or on the accent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, you need to call `setOpaque` false and override `contains(int,int)`.

Comment: Okay, but I found no "getpixel" like functions in the JLabel documentation. I need to render the text to some Image and use it as a reference?

Comment: Found it, Robot.getPixelColor.